# Gulp when SpringBoot Application starts

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, gulp

A little new to gulp, I understand the tasks part, just wondering if it is possible to make gulp run a default task when a spring boot application is started?

Answer (score 1):

Gulp (with conjunction to Spring Boot project) is usually used to bundle your front-end resources and run front-end JS tests. So you should execute Gulp tasks only from your Java build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle). You shouldn't execute it on runtime.